# Representing a collection of element IDs and values

Tags: javascript

I'm building a Chrome Extension and I need to store all the input elements' IDs and values for later use. What's the correct way to represent **"ID -> Value"** in Javascript? I was thinking about an array of objects with 2 strings. Is there anything more elegant?

Comment: Elegance is subjective. It really depends on what you're using the info for.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm assuming your `ID` will be unique, you should try using an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

```
var inputs = {
    'id1': 'value 1',
    'text': 'sometext'
}
```

Comment: if you can edit your answer and make it into an array of inputs and replace "'id2': 'value 2'" with "'text': 'sometext'" I'd gladly accept it.